# Road bike raises my heart rate more tahn my MTB?

Tags: road-bike, mountain-bike, heart-rate

I own a HRM that I use during most of my rides and I noticed that I manage to push myself to the limit when I ride my road bike but not with my MTB. My max HR is always higher with my road bike, my average HR likewise. Is there an explanation for this?

Comment: Are your MTB rides on the same road?  Or are you comparing an off-road MTB ride with an on-road trip with your road bike ?

Comment: Also, what are your average speeds for each bike?  30 km/h on road bike should be easier than 30 km/h on the MTB.  But 15 km/h on the MTB is very hard to compare with 30 on the road bike.

Comment: My guess is that your average level of effort is higher on the road bike.

Comment: @Daniel R Hicks: yes, that's my guess too but I wonder why is that. Whenever I willingly push myself on the MTB I never reach the same HR (180+ on the road bike is not uncommon if I choose to go there, I rarely ever reach 175 on the MTB).

Comment: @Criggie, when I'm comparing HRs it's on tarmac, it makes no sense otherwise IMO.

Comment: To be vaguley methodical, try getting a speedo that you can see while riding.  Strava on your phone in a top-tube bag or something.  Then ride a fixed route at a constant (fairly high) speed on your MTB, then ride the same route on your road bike but hold the speed to the same as the first run.   Just adjust your gears to be "comfortable" at that speed rather than aiming for a particular cadence.  A 15-30 minute circle route should be heaps, but try and avoid traffic lights so you don't have to stop.   Alternating 10 minute sessions in a velodrome would do too.

Answer (score 1):

Heart rate is not an indicator of effort - its an indicator of fitness.

The best tool for measuring effort is a power meter, but they're not cheap.  Everything else is an estimate of power, rather than a measurement.

Your heart rate and your breathing rates will rise as your muscles demand more oxygen.

Could be your cadence is higher on the road bike and you're spinning, where-as you're mashing on the MTB which leads to different muscle fibres being used.

Comment: This very much makes sense. I don't have a cadence meter but I believe I tend to spin on the road bike. I generally switch to whatever gear I feel allows me to maintain certain speeds on certain road portions I'm very familiar with.

Comment: Heart rate is not an indicator of effort?   Can you increase effort and not increase heart rate?   You have a strange sense of logic.

Comment: @Paparazzi Nope.  Consider a car's instrumentation.  The rev counter is a direct indicator of engine effort, the speedo is second-order measure, and temperature gauge is third-order.  Heart rate would be similar to the temperature in that its not a direct measure of effort, and measures the effect of effort.  Sorry for the car metaphor but it fits quite well here.